# Probability of a pair sitting next to each other from a group of 3 selected from a group of 25

Tags: probability, contest-math

During a round-table meeting, the CEO wanted to select a team of $3$ out $25$ marketing specialists to handle a new project. if the probability that $2$ of the $3$ selected specialists were sitting next to each other is $m \over n$, where $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime, find the value of $m+n$.

The denominator is $25C3$. How do I find the numerator?

Comment: You can minus all the probabilities where no one sits next to each other

Answer (score 1):

You have $25$ possible choices for the clockwise member of the pair that's sitting together.  Once you've selected that pair, (and assuming the question asks for *exactly* two members to be adjacent to one another), you can choose any of the $21$ remaining people who are not adjacent to the pair as the third member of your team.  so the answer is $\frac{25 \cdot 21 \cdot 6}{25 \cdot 24 \cdot 23}=\frac{21}{92}.$

Comment: This assumes, of course, that the the CEO himself isn't also sitting at the table, which is a bit ambiguous in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit 1:** I misinterpreted the question to mean that (at least) $2$ sit next to each other, so the following solution is incorrect. I'll leave it if anyone is interested in that case.

**Edit 2:** Even in that situation it wouldn't work (see the comments for the reason).

Let's label them from $0$ to $24$ and do arithmetic (with those labels) in $\mathbb{Z}_{25}$ as they sit in a round table.

We need to count the number of $3$-subsets of $\mathbb{Z}_{25}$ which are of the form $\{i, i+1, j\}$, $j \not \in  \{i, i+1\}$.

Let's call the set of such subsets $M$.

To not overcount, we can restrict ourselves to $j \neq i-1$ as $i' = j, j' = i+1$ would lead to the same set.

With that restriction, the question becomes equivalent to count pairs $(i,j) \in \mathbb{Z}_{25}^2$ with $j \not \in \{i-1, i, i+1\}$: Every subset in $M$ can obviously be created using one such pair and each pair maps uniquely to one subset in $M$.

Now, for $i$ we have $25$ possbilities and for $j$ $22$. So the numerator is $25 \cdot 22 = 550$.

Therefore, the probability is

$$\frac{550}{2300} = \frac{11}{46}.$$

Comment: Oh, yes, I'll edit that, thanks.

Comment: This isn't right.  If we're assuming we're not allowed all $3$ sitting adjacent to one another, then $j \neq i-1, i+2$.

Comment: Oh, I thought that was also allowed (i.e. that at least 2 sit next to each other). I'll mark it in my post.

Comment: Your answer still wouldn't be right because you'd be double-counting all of the combinations with three consecutive specialists -- once by putting the third team member on the left and a second time by putting the third team member on the right.

Comment: Right, that's correct. I'll mention that too. Thank you for the remarks.

Comment: Actually, I wrote too soon.  You did account correctly for that possibility by refusing to allow the third team member to be index $i-1$.  So your answer is correct if all three members can be consecutive.